# ERROR: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, migration

## npx sequelize-cli db:migrate run getting import error

Using environment "development".
== 20231015073945-create-role: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot use import statement outside a module

i am using .ts

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../connection/connection';

class Role extends Model {
  public id!: number;
  public role!: string;
  public isActive!: boolean;
  public createdAt!: Date;
  public updatedAt!: Date;
}

Role.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    isActive: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Role',
    tableName: 'roles',
  }
);

export default Role;
```